# Assembling Android library project with sub module dependency

Tags: android, gradle, android-library, aar

I have the following library project structure where **`sdk`** is the project that I assemble into an `aar` file for distribution

```
└─ ProjectRoot
   ├─ sdk
   │  ├─ build.gradle
   │  ├─ libs/
   │  └─ src/
   │
   ├─ submoduleRoot
   │  ├─ settings.gradle
   │  └─ projectA
   │     ├─ src/
   │     └─ build.gradle
   │
   ├─ settings.gradle
   └─ build.gradle
```

When I assemble the `*.aar` file and reference it in an Android Application project, I am seeing the following runtime exception.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/company/engine/MyClass
```

The `MyClass` which the App is complaining about is defined in `ProjectRoot/submoduleRoot/projectA/src/MyClass`

---

> ProjectRoot/settings.gradle

```
include ':sdk'
include ':projectA'
project(':projectA').projectDir = new File('submoduleRoot/projectA')
```

---

> ProjectRoot/sdk/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        develop {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
        }

    }

    sourceSets {
        sourceSets.androidTest.java.srcDirs = ["src/test/java"]
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':manticore')
    ...
}
```

Could you please let me know if there is anything I should be doing differently?